# Select Count of Certain Rows as Column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with a "status" column which accepts a `TINYINT`. For example:

```
name   | status
-------+--------
john   | 0
joe    | 1
johann | 0
jan    | 1
jane   | 0
```

How can I get a count of who is status 1 and who is status 0?

```
status1 | status0
--------+--------
2       | 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(status = 1) as status1, sum(status = 0) as status0
from t;
```

In your case, you could also write this as:

```
select sum(status) as status1, sum(1 - status) as status0
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a CASE statement to check for your value.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [status] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Status1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [status] = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Status0
FROM tbl;
```